# Interactive scanf using pipe

Tags: c, unix, console, pipe

I try to read a value from console in unix using pipe

exmpl.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int d;
 scanf("%d",&d);
 printf("d=%d",d);
 return 0;
]
```

So, when i use

```
./a.out < tmp
```

I get the number from tmp immidiately, but i want to get number from console

Also, I tried to use

```
fscanf(stdin, "%d",&d);
```

but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that. With `<` you've changed the stdin of the program, therefore you can't use stdin for user interaction anymore.

Consider using `tmp` file as an argument.

Comment: What about int  read(  int  handle,  void  *buffer,  int  nbyte )? I couldnt correctly use it, but can it be a solution?

Comment: Which handle would you use. You've changed (lost) 0/stdin already. I guess you could try read from 1 (stdout), or opening something in /dev/, although that feels hacky even when I'm typing it, and it's not portable in any case.